# Strange behaviour of free() after memory allocation violation

Tags: c, memory-management, segmentation-fault

Not so long ago I was hunting a bug in some big number library I was writing, it costed me quite a while. The problem was that I violated the memory bounds of some structure member, but instead of a `segmentation fault` or just a plain crash, it did something unexpected (at least I did not expect it). Let me introduce a example:

**segmentation_fault.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define N 100 /* arbitrary large number */

typedef unsigned char byte;

void exitError(char *);
void segmentationFaultSignalHandler(int);

sig_atomic_t segmentationFaultFlag = 0;


int main(void)
{
    int i, memorySize = 0;
    byte *memory;
    if (setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0))
        exitError("setvbuf() failed");
    if (signal(SIGSEGV, segmentationFaultSignalHandler) == SIG_ERR)
        exitError("signal() failed");
    for (i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        printf("Before malloc()\n");
        if ((memory = malloc(++memorySize * sizeof(byte))) == NULL)
            exitError("allocation failed");
        printf("After malloc()\n");
        printf("Before segmentation fault\n");
        memory[memorySize] = 0x0D; /* segmentation fault */
        if (segmentationFaultFlag)
            exitError("detected segmentation fault");
        printf("After segmentation fault\n");
        printf("Before free()\n");
        free(memory);
        printf("After free()\n");
    }
    return 0;
}


void segmentationFaultSignalHandler(int signal)
{
    segmentationFaultFlag = 1;
}


void exitError(char *errorMessage)
{
    printf("ERROR: %s, errno=%d.\n", errorMessage, errno);
    exit(1);
}
```

As we can see the line `memory[memorySize] = 0x0D;` is clearly violating the memory bounds given by `malloc()`, but it does not crash or raise a signal (I know according to ISO C99 / ISO C11 the signal handling is implementation defined and does not have to raise at all when violating memory bounds). It moves on printing the lines `After segmentation fault`, `Before free()` and `After free()`, but after a couple of iterations later it crashes, always at `free()` (printing `After segmentation fault` and `Before free()`, but not `After free()`). I was wondering what causes this behavior and what is the best way to detect memory access violations (I'm ashamed, but I always kinda used `printf`s to determine where a program crashed, but sure there must be better tools to do that) as it is very hard to detect (most often it does not crash at the code of violation, but, as in the example, later in the code, when trying to do something with this memory again). Surely I should be able to free this memory as I allocated it right and did not modify the pointer.

Comment: This is Undefined Behaviour. As the name implies, "Undefined Behaviour" means anything can happen, there is no crash garanty, just... anything.

Comment: Undefined behavior is, by definition, undefined. It can cause a crash (segmentation fault (or other)), it can *seem* to work fine, or it may crash in a completely unrelated place or even cause [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

Comment: The reason it can cause problem with `free` is that some allocation algorithms (especially in debugging mode) stores data outside of the allocated memory.

Comment: That is interesting, but of course explains it all. Thanks a lot! (do you have some references to these allocation algorithms?)

Comment: usually undefined behavior becomes apparent as you are showing your product to a customer.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, Just one thing left: why did this code succeed for a couple of iterations? If it damaged fatal parts of the allocation information wouldn't `free()` crash the first time?

Comment: That's the thing with undefined behavior. It can *seem* to work sometimes, but in reality bad things are happening. Doing undefined things multiple times will only cause the problems to cascade until an inevitable crash. Or, it may be that the first calls are actually valid, and it's not until you do the invalid `free` that the crash happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When reading or writing in memory you don't own you get undefined behavior.

This doesn't always result in segmentation fault. In practise it is much more likely that the code will corrupt some other data and your program will crash at some other place which makes it hard to debug.

In this example you wrote to an invalid heap address. It's likely that you will corrupt some internal heap structures which makes it likely that the program will crash on any following malloc or free calls.

There are tools that check your heap usage and can tell you if you write out of your bounds. I like and would recommend valgrind for linux and gflags for windows.

Comment: Just to precise. Writting to a completely random address more likely touches undefined and unallocated memory. If you compare a "normal" size of a running program which is several megabytes to the size of the addressable space which is 2^32 (or 2^64), the probability to touch the code or data is around 1:1000 (or 1:2^40).

Answer (score 3):

You only can detect violations in an faked enviroment.
In the case, you violate the Memory you gained from the system, you can't belive anything anymore. As all what happens now is undefined behaving and you CAN'T expect what will happen, as there isn't any rule.

So if you want to check a program for memory leacks or some read/write violation. you have to write a program which gets a memory area which belongs to it and you give a part of the area to the "to be checked" program. You have to inspect the process and keep track on where it is writing and reading into our memory and you have to use the other part of the memory to check for was it allowed to read write there or not (i.e. In your faked enviroment by setting some FLAGS and check they got changed or not).

Because if the program is leaving the area you own. you can't be sure about you will detect this behaving or not.
So You have to make your own memory managemend to check such behaving.

Answer (score 2):

When malloc is returning a pointer to a chunk of memory, it uses some additional information about this pointer (like the size of allocated space). This information is usually stored on addresses right before the returned pointer. Also very often, malloc can return a pointer to bigger chunk than you asked for. In consequence addresses before and after the pointer are valid. You can write there without provoking segmentation fault or other system error. However, if you write there you may overwrite the data malloc needs for correct freeing of the memory. The behavior of subsequent calls of malloc and free is undefined since this point.